# Split строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида `"x = 1.3 ,         Y =           15.3         "`

Мне нужно при вызове сплита с регулярным выражением, получить 2 числа(координаты). 
Пробовал сплитить таким

```
s.split("[\\s][,]([\\s]){0,}[a-zA-Z][\\s][=]([\\s]){0,}");
```

Вывод такой:

```
x = 1.3;
15.3;
```

Как мне в сплите пропустить сами числа? До числа первого не сплитит и не режет пробелы после.

Comment: А есть смысл изобретать такое? Сделайте `replaceAll()` - почистите строку от мусора, потом уже `split()`.

Comment: И зачем сплит, если обычный поиск по регулярке наверняка возвращает готовый массив групп захвата

Comment: @Mike пример кода можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**String.split:**

```
String str = "x = 1.3 ,         Y =           15.3         ";
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( str.split( "[^\\d\\.]+" ) ) );
// [, 1.3, 15.3]
```

Разбивает строку по разделителям в которые не входят цифры и точка. Поскольку строка начинается с разделителя, первой в массиве идет пустая строка.

**Регулярное выражение:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)[^\\d]+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( str );
if ( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.printf( "[%s, %s]%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2) );
}
// [1.3, 15.3]
```

Ищет две последовательности цифр, возможно заканчивающихся точкой и еще последовательностью цифр, разделенных последовательностью не цифр. Можно записать регулярку так: `" *x *= *(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) *, *Y *= *(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*"`, тогда она еще соответствие строки будет проверять.

**Получение из строки чисел подряд:**

```
pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)" );
matcher = pattern.matcher( str );
String[] result = new String[2];
matcher.find();
result[0] = matcher.group();
matcher.find();
result[1] = matcher.group();
```

Вызов `matcher.find()` ищет новое соответствие с первого символа, не попавшего в предыдущее соответствие, `matcher.group()` возвращает всю подстроку, совпавшую с регулярным выражением.

Метода, типа `String[] matcher.findAll()`, к сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 5):

Как и предложил enzo: сначала очистить строку с помощью replaceAll(), а затем разбить на две подстроки с помощью split().

```
String str = "x = 1.3 ,         Y =           15.3         ";
str = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z =]+", "");
String[] parts = str.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 1.3
String part2 = parts[1]; // 15.3
```